# An exception occurred processing the request: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Just checked the WildFly log of a system that I developed and found the following error on it:

```
2017-05-03 08:48:08,575 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005001: An exception occurred processing the request: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: https://www.google.com:443http://www.google.com/
at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:672)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SinglePortConfidentialityHandler.getRedirectURI(SinglePortConfidentialityHandler.java:51)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.getRedirectURI(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:83)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:49)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Besides *https://www.google.com:443http://www.google.com/* there is also *https://testp3.pospr.waw.pl:443http://testp3.pospr.waw.pl/testproxy.php* and *https://www.baidu.com:443http://www.baidu.com/cache/global/img/gs.gif*.

Someone knows what could be the problem?

Edit:
A few hours after this log there was a ***java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*** and the system crashed, making it needed to restart WildFly to get the system up again. I can't say for sure if the crash is related with this error.

Comment: any code you can post from where that is being thrown?

Comment: All the classes on this log are originated from Java. In the log file, what comes after this is exactly the same, but changing from google.com to, for example, baidu.com. I don't know what originated this log, i.e., wich page.

Comment: Wasn't sure if that was the whole trace or not.  That's why I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is caused by web scanners executed on the website.

For more info about it: https://issues.redhat.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/UNDERTOW-592.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that someone is sending you a URL in the following form:

```
http://yoursite.com/https://www.google.com:443http://www.google.com/
```

Try sending that URL form your browser and see if you get similar error.

Comment: It goes to a error page, but on the log there's anything.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try... Sorry.